# Multiple assignee controls in Alfresco Workflow form

Tags: jakarta-ee, alfresco

I'm required to build a workflow that allows the admin to select two assignees from two different groups in the first task of the workflow. Can I use two assignee controls in one form ? How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to:

- In the task content model, define the 2 assignees as 2 seperate associations of your task type.

  ```
      <type name="my:starttask">
      <parent>bpm:startTask</parent>
        <associations>
          <association name="my:firstassignee">
              <title>firstassignee</title>
              <source>
                  <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                  <many>false</many>
              </source>
              <target>
                  <class>cm:person</class>
                  <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                  <many>false</many>
              </target>
          </association>
          <association name="my:secondassignee">
              <title>secondassignee</title>
              <source>
                  <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                  <many>false</many>
              </source>
              <target>
                  <class>cm:person</class>
                  <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                  <many>false</many>
              </target>
          </association>
      </associations>
     </type>
  ```
- In your share config custom, define the 2 associations as authority controls:

  ```
        <config condition="activiti$myworkflow" evaluator="string-compare">
          <forms>
           <form>
          <field-visibility>
              <show id="my:firstassignee" />
              <show id="my:secondassignee" />
           </field-visibility>
          <appearance>
              <field set="actors" id="my:firstassignee" >
                  <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/authority.ftl">

                  </control>
              </field>

              <field set="actors" id="my:secondassignee">
                  <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/authority.ftl">

                  </control>
              </field>
  ```
- In your bpm20 file, define two ActivitiScriptNode vars in your process and an ExecutionListener to the usertask/starttask having the two cm:person associations. That execution listener should be taking the entered values and placing them into the process scoped variables like this:

  ```
    <extensionElements>
      <activiti:taskListener class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener" event="complete">
        <activiti:field name="script">
          <activiti:string>
             execution.setVariable('firstActivitiScriptNodeVar', task.getVariable('my_firstassignee'));
             execution.setVariable('secondActivitiScriptNodeVar', task.getVariable('my_secondassignee'));
          </activiti:string>
        </activiti:field>
      </activiti:taskListener>
    </extensionElements>
  ```
- Then add this code to the UserTasks you which to assign to the entered users like this:

  ```
  <humanPerformer>
              <resourceAssignmentExpression>
                  <formalExpression>${firstActivitiScriptNodeVar.properties.userName}</formalExpression>
              </resourceAssignmentExpression>
  </humanPerformer>
  ```

Comment: thanks alot !! but how can I assign the use to appropriate process variables ? 
I'm trying to use an executionlistener inside the start event with the event property set to end but it's not working

Comment: @yreg excuse me but I'm new to alfresco, how are the ActivitiScriptNode vars defined? are they the regular vars inside the execution listener ??

Comment: @basil I updated the post with code snippet for exporting task local vars to the current execution

Comment: @YReg when I use the <humanPerformer> tag to assign the tasks to users in vars the workflow fails to start with no output other than stating that it's a WorkflowException, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a paste with your full workflow / or at least the part of it related to this question ? you can use pastebin.com for that

Comment: here is a full paste, and thanks for you continuous help :)
here is my workflow model
http://pastebin.com/jX3W9CsQ
and the related snippet of my workflow bpm file
http://pastebin.com/LgWNsmnh