# Alfresco - assigning tasks to different assignees in custom workflow

Tags: javascript, java, workflow, alfresco, business-process-management

I'm trying to create a custom workflow, where at the start of the workflow, the workflow initiator can choose 3 users to perform different tasks in the workflow (in this case, an author, a reviewer, and an approver).

To do this I am defining each of these roles as an aspect of my start task in my workflow model, and then I am trying to assign these users to process variables in the workflow and assign the tasks to them through the activiti:assignee task. In my share-config-custom I am defining the roles as authority controls. I am following the process described in: 
[Multiple assignee controls in Alfresco Workflow form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34612055/multiple-assignee-controls-in-alfresco-workflow-form)

The workflow starts without a problem, and Alfresco allows me to select users, but the task assignment does not work. In the workflow history, it says that the task is assigned to "$(author.properties.userName)", which is the expression I use in my bpmn file, but it is not picking up the userName of the author variable.

I have attached links to my files below. If there is a problem with them, or if there is a better method of achieving this goal, please let me know!

Many thanks

Marcus

bpmn file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By5ruty8M4IleWlKSmdQNUNXR0k/view?usp=sharing

workflowModel file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By5ruty8M4IlVEFlSWo2SElNNUE/view?usp=sharing

I will post the share-config-custom in the comments

Comment: share-config-custom: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By5ruty8M4IlTFRWNHhmN29fWTQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you try reviewing the BPMN files of the built-in Alfresco workflows, to see how it's done there?

Comment: task.getVariable('vorwf_author') you are trying to get author by using this.
can you please explain this line returns userName???.

Comment: @Gagravarr unfortunately I do not think there is an example workflow where you can choose multiple assignees. All the workflow use bpm:assignee which only works when there is one assignee in the task...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to figure out how to do this! Firstly, I define each 'role' in the workflow as an aspect in my workflowModel.xml file. Here is an example for one of the roles, author:

```
<aspects>
    <aspect name="vorwf:author">
        <associations>
            <association name="vorwf:author">
                <source>
                    <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                    <many>false</many>
                </source>
                <target>
                    <class>cm:person</class>
                    <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                    <many>false</many>
                </target>
            </association>  
        </associations>
    </aspect>
```

I then set these roles as mandatory aspects in the definition of the task where the user roles are defined:

```
 <type name="vorwf:allocateDocumentProperties">
        <parent>bpm:startTask</parent>
        <properties>
            <property name="vorwf:approveRejectOutcome">
                <type>d:text</type>
                <default>Reject</default>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint type="LIST">
                        <parameter name="allowedValues">
                            <list>
                                <value>Approve</value>
                                <value>Reject</value>
                            </list>
                        </parameter>
                    </constraint>
                </constraints>
            </property>
        </properties>
        <mandatory-aspects>
            <aspect>vorwf:author</aspect>
            <aspect>vorwf:reviewer</aspect>
            <aspect>vorwf:approver</aspect>
        </mandatory-aspects>
    </type>
```

Finally, I can assign the task to the user in my bpmn file, without having to set any other variables, for example:

```
<userTask id="prepareDocument" name="Prepare Document" activiti:assignee="${vorwf_author.properties.userName}" activiti:formKey="vorwf:prepareDocument">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
execution.setVariable('author', task.getVariable('vorwf_author'));
```

you are setting a variable `author` and
you are trying to assign a task to author by using `$(author.properties.userName)`

here `author` is not an object so you can not find userName. if you wanted to do it so you have to create user object

example : enter your user name

```
 var author=people.getPerson("user_name");
 var authVar=author.properties.userName;
```

set variable

```
execution.setVariable('my_author',authVar);
```

and you can access it by using `${my_author}`

### Or

if you are getting userName of author by this `task.getVariable('vorwf_author')`

```
 execution.setVariable('author', task.getVariable('vorwf_author'));
```

then you can simply use `${author}`

Comment: thanks for your answer, I think you are right that the problem is that the author variable does not have a userName property. However, I'm struggling to implement your suggested solution, because I cannot simply enter the "user_name" in the workflow code.

I need a way to extract the userName from the vorwf_author object, so that each time I start the workflow I can choose which user is assigned the task. I do not think my workflow is picking this up correctly

Comment: yes my means do not enter user_name manually replace it with your dynamic value

Comment: execution.setVariable('author', task.getVariable('vorwf_author'));
using this author if it gives value as userName so you can use it as ${author}

Comment: this was the way I tried originally but I do not think it is giving me back the userName. So in fact I am wondering if vorwf_author is actually being set the way I think it is being set? Perhaps it is not actually being related to the user that I choose in the workflow form? Do you think this is a problem with my files?

Comment: No there is problem in your assignee.

Comment: what do you mean there is a problem with my assignee? Is it the assignee object that is not working?

Comment: Means by using your way you may not get the assignee username

Comment: please try with ${author}

Comment: Hi @vikash, sorry for the late response. I've been busy with other things and have not had time to work on my alfresco project.

I've managed to solve my problem, and in fact the simplest solution works the best. I first defined my various users (author, reviewer, approver) as aspects in my workflow model file, and called these as mandatory aspects in the task model. Then I simply used ${vorwf_author.properties.userName} as my assignee, without having to set any variables. Thank you for your help!