# Customize workflow alfresco multiple assignee

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti, bpmn, alfresco-maven

I'm try multiple assignee from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34612055/multiple-assignee-controls-in-alfresco-workflow-form)

The workflow starts a problem. and Model has error

[image]

Model error:

```
WARN  (searcherExecutor-21-thread-1-processing-x:alfresco) [   x:alfresco] o.a.s.AlfrescoSolrDataModel Model not updated: exwf:workflowmodel   Failed to validate model update - found non-incrementally updated TYPE '{http://www.extest.com/model/workflow/1.0}submitConcurrentReviewTask'
```

I have attached links to my files below. If there is a problem with them, or if there is a better method of achieving this goal, please let me know!

Many thanks

bpmn20 file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mLu9sUUuRp779RNVoPGud0tLkiLdK8oD/view?usp=sharing

model file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12UvXOy_DsCUin4M4zG07edmZLHsLceh5/view?usp=sharing

share-config-custom file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MLRtbHf75ekWD4a2tx7bzQoCbXrJGPIf/view?usp=sharing

log : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xbwu18DTOJDBMr_-Bz-gHa4SDI3arDAZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Does your workflow include a custom script at any steps?

Comment: No, them doesn’t. Just start workflow.
I select two assignees from two different groups and different tasks. thanks